Building Kivy app using PyInstaller with GitHub Actions
I am attempting to build a Kivy app into a single .exe file using pyinstaller, using GitHub Actions. Below is my MWE
main.py
# main.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello, Kivy!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyKivyApp().run()

.github/workflows/build-win.yml
name: Build Kivy App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: '3.12'

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install kivy pyinstaller

    - name: Build with PyInstaller
      run: |
        pyinstaller --onefile main.py

    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: kivy-app
        path: dist/main.exe

However this seems to result in some odd behaviour. When PyInstaller tries to run the import hooks, it initialises Kivy, which then fails because it can't start sdl2 on the headless GitHub Actions worker:
Run pyinstaller --onefile main.py
  pyinstaller --onefile main.py
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    pythonLocation: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64
2219 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.7.0, contrib hooks: 2024.6
2219 INFO: Python: 3.12.3
2235 INFO: Platform: Windows-2022Server-10.0.20348-SP0
2235 INFO: wrote D:\a\kivyapp1\kivyapp1\main.spec
2235 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\a\\kivyapp1\\kivyapp1']
2407 INFO: checking Analysis
2407 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
2407 INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
2407 INFO: Target bytecode optimization level: 0
2407 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
2407 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
2422 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3987 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.3\\x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6191 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.3\\x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7614 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.3\\x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
8600 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
8694 INFO: Looking for Python shared library...
8788 INFO: Using Python shared library: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\python312.dll
8788 INFO: Analyzing D:\a\kivyapp1\kivyapp1\main.py
8804 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-kivy.py' from 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.3\\x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
8819 WARNING: Config: Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 27)
Warning:  [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 27)
8819 WARNING: Config: Upgrading configuration in progress.
Warning:  [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
8819 DEBUG: Config: Upgrading from 0 to 1
[DEBUG  ] [Config      ] Upgrading from 0 to 1
8819 INFO: deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
8819 INFO: Logger: Record log in C:\Users\runneradmin\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-05-24_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\runneradmin\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-05-24_0.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
8819 INFO: deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
8819 INFO: deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
8835 INFO: Kivy: v2.3.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
8835 INFO: Kivy: Installed at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
8835 INFO: Python: v3.12.3 (tags/v3.12.3:f6650f9, Apr  9 2024, 14:05:25) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.12.3 (tags/v3.12.3:f6650f9, Apr  9 2024, 14:05:25) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
8835 INFO: Python: Interpreter at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\python.exe"
8835 INFO: Logger: Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
8835 INFO: Logger: Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
8835 INFO: Factory: 195 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 195 symbols loaded
8835 DEBUG: Collecting submodules for kivy.graphics
[DEBUG  ] Collecting submodules for kivy.graphics
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\runneradmin\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-05-24_1.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.12.3 (tags/v3.12.3:f6650f9, Apr  9 2024, 14:05:25) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
125 INFO: deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
125 INFO: Logger: Record log in C:\Users\runneradmin\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-05-24_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\runneradmin\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-05-24_2.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
125 INFO: deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
125 INFO: deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
125 INFO: Kivy: v2.3.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
125 INFO: Kivy: Installed at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
125 INFO: Python: v3.12.3 (tags/v3.12.3:f6650f9, Apr  9 2024, 14:05:25) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.12.3 (tags/v3.12.3:f6650f9, Apr  9 2024, 14:05:25) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
125 INFO: Python: Interpreter at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\python.exe"
125 INFO: Logger: Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
125 INFO: Logger: Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
187 INFO: Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
187 DEBUG: collect_submodules - scanning (sub)package kivy.graphics in location(s): ['C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.3\\x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\graphics']
[DEBUG  ] [collect_submodules - scanning (sub)package kivy.graphics in location(s)] ['C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.3\\x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\graphics']
187 DEBUG: collect_submodules - scanning (sub)package kivy.graphics.cgl_backend
[DEBUG  ] collect_submodules - scanning (sub)package kivy.graphics.cgl_backend
187 DEBUG: collect_submodules - scanning (sub)package kivy.graphics.cgl_backend in location(s): ['C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.3\\x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\graphics\\cgl_backend']
[DEBUG  ] [collect_submodules - scanning (sub)package kivy.graphics.cgl_backend in location(s)] ['C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.3\\x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\graphics\\cgl_backend']
9257 DEBUG: collect_submodules - found submodules: ['kivy.graphics', 'kivy.graphics.boxshadow', 'kivy.graphics.buffer', 'kivy.graphics.cgl', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_debug', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_gl', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_glew', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_mock', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_sdl2', 'kivy.graphics.compiler', 'kivy.graphics.context', 'kivy.graphics.context_instructions', 'kivy.graphics.fbo', 'kivy.graphics.gl_instructions', 'kivy.graphics.instructions', 'kivy.graphics.opengl', 'kivy.graphics.opengl_utils', 'kivy.graphics.scissor_instructions', 'kivy.graphics.shader', 'kivy.graphics.stencil_instructions', 'kivy.graphics.svg', 'kivy.graphics.tesselator', 'kivy.graphics.texture', 'kivy.graphics.transformation', 'kivy.graphics.vbo', 'kivy.graphics.vertex', 'kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions']
[DEBUG  ] [collect_submodules - found submodules] ['kivy.graphics', 'kivy.graphics.boxshadow', 'kivy.graphics.buffer', 'kivy.graphics.cgl', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_debug', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_gl', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_glew', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_mock', 'kivy.graphics.cgl_backend.cgl_sdl2', 'kivy.graphics.compiler', 'kivy.graphics.context', 'kivy.graphics.context_instructions', 'kivy.graphics.fbo', 'kivy.graphics.gl_instructions', 'kivy.graphics.instructions', 'kivy.graphics.opengl', 'kivy.graphics.opengl_utils', 'kivy.graphics.scissor_instructions', 'kivy.graphics.shader', 'kivy.graphics.stencil_instructions', 'kivy.graphics.svg', 'kivy.graphics.tesselator', 'kivy.graphics.texture', 'kivy.graphics.transformation', 'kivy.graphics.vbo', 'kivy.graphics.vertex', 'kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions']
9257 WARNING: Could not find GStreamer plugins. Possible solution: set GST_PLUGIN_PATH
Warning:  [Could not find GStreamer plugins. Possible solution] set GST_PLUGIN_PATH
9257 DEBUG: Collecting submodules for kivy.core
[DEBUG  ] Collecting submodules for kivy.core
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\runneradmin\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-05-24_3.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.12.3 (tags/v3.12.3:f6650f9, Apr  9 2024, 14:05:25) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
125 INFO: deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
125 INFO: Logger: Record log in C:\Users\runneradmin\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-05-24_4.txt
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\runneradmin\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-05-24_4.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
125 INFO: deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
125 INFO: deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
125 INFO: Kivy: v2.3.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
125 INFO: Kivy: Installed at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
125 INFO: Python: v3.12.3 (tags/v3.12.3:f6650f9, Apr  9 2024, 14:05:25) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.12.3 (tags/v3.12.3:f6650f9, Apr  9 2024, 14:05:25) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
125 INFO: Python: Interpreter at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.12.3\x64\python.exe"
125 INFO: Logger: Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
125 INFO: Logger: Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
125 DEBUG: collect_submodules - scanning (sub)package kivy.core in location(s): ['C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.3\\x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\core']
[DEBUG  ] [collect_submodules - scanning (sub)package kivy.core in location(s)] ['C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.12.3\\x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\core']
125 DEBUG: collect_submodules - scanning (sub)package kivy.core.window
[DEBUG  ] collect_submodules - scanning (sub)package kivy.core.window
156 INFO: Factory: 195 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 195 symbols loaded
234 INFO: Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
265 INFO: Window: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
1109 INFO: GL: Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
1110 INFO: GL: GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
1110 INFO: GL: No framebuffers extension is supported
[INFO   ] [GL          ] No framebuffers extension is supported
1110 INFO: GL: Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
1110 INFO: GL: OpenGL version <b'1.1.0'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'1.1.0'>
1110 INFO: GL: OpenGL vendor <b'Microsoft Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Microsoft Corporation'>
1110 INFO: GL: OpenGL renderer <b'GDI Generic'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GDI Generic'>
1111 INFO: GL: OpenGL parsed version: 1, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 1, 1
1111 CRITICAL: GL: Minimum required OpenGL version (2.0) NOT found!

OpenGL version detected: 1.1

Version: b'1.1.0'
Vendor: b'Microsoft Corporation'
Renderer: b'GDI Generic'

Try upgrading your graphics drivers and/or your graphics hardware in case of problems.

The application will leave now.
[CRITICAL] [GL          ] Minimum required OpenGL version (2.0) NOT found!

OpenGL version detected: 1.1

Version: b'1.1.0'
Vendor: b'Microsoft Corporation'
Renderer: b'GDI Generic'

Try upgrading your graphics drivers and/or your graphics hardware in case of problems.

The application will leave now.
Error: The operation was canceled.

It hangs at the last step and I need to cancel the workflow.

You are probably missing dependencies, maybe add KivyMD to the pip installs
Btw, where did you learn to make this pipeline for kivy apps? I've been needing a CI/CD pipeline for my kivy desktop app
